# How can I replace all \r\n with \n using Komodo Edit

Tags: newlines, carriage-return, komodo

Somehow, some 40 files (mostly Python modules) in my project have `\r\n` (Windows style) as line endings. I'd like to change them to `\n` (Unix style) line endings, but Komodo Edit doesn't appear to provide a way change existing files' line endings, and a simple regexp find and replace using Komodo doesn't work either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There *is* actually a built-in feature for this in Komodo, but it's hard to find.

Right-click the `Edit` tab select `Current File Settings`. Under `File Settings`, change "Line Endings" to UNIX (\n) and de-select "Preserve existing line endings".

This is fine for individual files, but it would be a bit of a hassle if you were trying to do several files as a batch. For that, you could wrap some of swatso33's suggestions into a [saved command](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.0/run.html) using [interpolation shortcuts](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.0/shortcuts.html).

**UPDATE (2014-10-13):** There is now an option: `Clean Line Endings` under the `Code` tab.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I ended up spendin 20 minutes last night changing them by doing open file -> copy contents -> command w -> close and delete file -> command shift t (which prompts to recreate the file) -> paste contents -> save. I got each one down to about 8 seconds by the end lol, but wasted time early on doing extra steps.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with either perl or sed using:

```
 perl -pe 's/\r?\n|\r/\r\n/g' inputfile > outputfile  # Convert to DOS.
 perl -pe 's/\r?\n|\r/\n/g'   inputfile > outputfile  # Convert to UNIX.
 sed -e 's/$/\r/' inputfile > outputfile              # UNIX to DOS  (adding CRs on Linux based OS that use GNU extensions).
 sed -e 's/\r$//' inputfile > outputfile              # DOS  to UNIX (removing CRs on Linux based OS that use GNU extensions).
 perl -pe 's/\r?\n|\r/\r/g'   inputfile > outputfile  # Convert to old Mac.
```

Code snippet is from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Conversion_utilities

Answer (score 1):

At http://bugs.activestate.com/show_bug.cgi?id=93976 I give a macro
that changes the line-end setting and the actual line-endings when a
file that is under Git SCC is opened in Komodo.

You can also modify that macro to quickly update all loaded files.

Answer (score 0):

With Komodo[edit], one can control replacements of <kbd>CR</kbd> manually using regular expressions replacement tool. Same goes for most popular editors. This used to work great with np++.
Here is the way to go with Komodo:

1. Fill in *Find* input with `\r`
   [image]
2. Then make sure to switch on **BOTH** following options
   **"Treat the pattern as a regular expression"** (No need explanation)
   **"Use Multiple Lines"**  (Search will treat file content as a whole and not line by line. As a consequence pattern will match any characters until it fails, including <kbd>CR</kbd>, <kbd>LF</kbd>, etc. )

   [image]